# How to pass one array elements as an index to another array in c

Tags: c

I have two matrices `path[max][2]` and `input_pair2[max][max]` where max is 10 and path_count is dynamic and less than max (let's say 6). I want to use elements of path matrix as an index of input_pair2, i am doing this as in the following code. This works fine with c compiler but giving error in the framework i am using the code in. I am using framework for converting functions to circuits. The error indicates problem of assigning values 0 and 1 to the input_pair2 matrix.

```
typedef struct
{
   int input_pair1[max][max];
   int input_pair2[max][max];
}Pair;

typedef struct
{
  int array[max][2];
  int count;
}paths;

Pair augment_path(paths path, Pair pair )
{
     for (int p = 0; p < path.count; p++)
    {
       if (pair.input_pair2[path.array[p] [0]] [path.array[p][1]] == 1)

            pair.input_pair2[path.array[p][0]] [path.array[p][1]] = 0;

      else

            pair.input_pair2[path.array[p][0]] [path.array[p][1]] = 1;
   }
   return pair;
}
```

The error i get is,

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
what(): Unknown literal: 14100. Did you forget to return a value or assign a value to a OUTPUT variable?
Makefile:8: recipe for target 'output.gate.txt' failed
make: *** [output.gate.txt] Aborted (core dumped)
```

When i comment the above given code, error vanishes and circuits are generated.

Comment: Can you show what `path` array contains? just to make sure you are not accessing out of bound for `pair`.

Comment: Provide a [mcve]. Also, the error message suggests some C++ involvement, but you have tagged the question with C. Are you sure you are compiling the code as C and not C++?

Comment: It would be a lot more efficient if you would declare them as pointers, `Pair *augment_path(paths *path, Pair *pair )`

Comment: path array - 2 0

Comment: The problem has less to do with C than with this mysterious _framework_ you mention. What is it?